# How to generate jQuery auto complete tags from jQuery .each result

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I want to populate tags of jQuery autocomplete from result of .each in jQuery
how can I do it any help is appreciated.

My Code:

```
var availableTags ="";
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
  var Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
  var Contact = Title+",";
      Contact +=Contact;

       availableTags[Contact];
   });
```

the jQuery auto complete requires a variable like bellow:

```
var availableTags = [

  "ActionScript",

  "Clojure",

  "COBOL",

  "Scheme"

  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array. So create the array. Something like this:

```
var availableTags = [];
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
  availableTags.push($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
});
//just in case for development purpose
console.log(availableTags);
```

Or even better:

```
var availableTags = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row")
   .map(function() {
     //**this** is an element of the jquery object
     return $(this).attr("ows_Title");}) //returns jquery object
  .get(); //converts jquery object to array
```

Comment: Great and Clean, Thank you so much it worked perfect, thank :)